# Riesz-Kolmogorov more general

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I have a question about Riesz Kolmogorov Frechet.

$X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ measurable and $1\leq p<\infty$.
A set $A\subset L^p(X)$ is precompact if and only if

$ sup_{f\in A} ||f||_{L^p(X)} < \infty$

$sup_{f\in A} ||\overline{{ f}}(\cdot+h)-\overline{{ f}}||_{L^p(X \cup (X-h))}\rightarrow0$ for $|h|\rightarrow 0$

$sup_{f\in A} ||f||_{L^p(X/B_R(0))}\rightarrow 0$ for $R \rightarrow 0$

where $\overline{ f}$ is the trivial $0$ extension on $\mathbb{R}^n$

The difference i spot is that its $L^p(X)$ instead of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\overline{{ f}}$ instead of $f$.
I dont see how to prove this though. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!
Your question is a bit unclear to me: the set $A$ doesn't seem to be involved in the definition. Also, what is $f$? And over what set does the supremum run?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier you are right. its $f \in A$